# Programa desea finaliza s/n C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++, c++98

Quiero hacer un programa que me de la opcion de salir o no ya tengo todo hecho, lo unico que le falta a mi programa es la opcion de salida aqui muestro mi codigo, no entiendo porque me sale error.

```
int main()
 {
    char pre;
    do{
       cout<<"\Desea salir (s/n): "<<endl;
       cin>>pre;
    }while (pre=='s' || pre=='S'); 
    cout<<"--FIN DEL PROGRAMA"<<endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qué error da? La condición para estar dentro del bucle es que la respuesta sea 's' o 'S', luego no saldrá si pulsas una de esas letras.

Comment: No entiendo ¿Cuál error?

Comment: @user3733164 tiene razón, la condición está al revés, quieres seguir en el ciclo si no es `s` o `S`

Answer (score 1):

Leer caracter a caracter tiene sus problemas:

```
char c;
std::cin >> c;
```

Al hacerlo así, los saltos de línea serán leídos como un caracter más, lo cual hace que te salgan mensajes repetidos y que el efecto resultante no sea agradable.

Para evitar esto tienes que vacía el buffer de entrada cada vez:

```
char c;
std::cin >> c;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
```

Como ves, el proceso es un poco engorroso. Tal vez sea preferible, por tanto, usar `std::string`:

```
std::string respuesta;
std::cin >> respuesta;
```

Esta sobrecarga del operador `>>` sí elimina los saltos de línea, que no aparecerán en la variable.

Otra cosa que hay que cambiar en tu código es la condición del `while`. Tal y como está escrito en tu código, el programa te repetirá la pregunta indefinidamente mientras respondas que sí, cuando tu pretendes justamente lo contrario:

```
int main()
{
    std::string pre;
    do{
        cout<<"\Desea salir (s/n): "<<endl;
        cin>>pre;
    }while (pre!="s" && pre!="S"); 
    cout<<"--FIN DEL PROGRAMA"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar el tipo de dato string

```
string pre;
```

luego utilizar el metodo `cadena.substr(0,1)` con eso obtendremos la primera letra con que inicia la respuesta segun esta condicion comparar en la argumento de do while
Recuerda que "n" o "N" es para no salir ,ya que tu confuncion va ahi

```
int main()
{
    string pre;
    do{
       cout<<"Desea salir (s/n): "<<endl;
       cin>>pre;
    }while (pre.substr(0,1)=="n" || pre.substr(0,1)=="N"); 

    cout<<"--FIN DEL PROGRAMA"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Y si el usuario introduce algo tal que "abcd"? ¿Es correcto que en ese caso se cierre el programa?